# Using css style selector in JQuery not working?

Tags: jquery, html

Here is the working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/iorgu/szs90ykr/

The problem is that it's not working when I add "`.productrating-param`" to `img` like this:

```
$('.productrating-param img').after(mylayer.text());
```

What am I doing wrong?

```js
var mylayer=$('.label-count').clone();

$('.productrating-param img').after(mylayer.text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="label-count">7</div>
    <td class="param-value productrating-param">
        <img src="http://www.lamianaturashop.com/custom/kencekonyha/catalog/view/theme/rome_cappuccino/image/stars_5.png" alt="5 / 5 csillag!" >
    </td>
```

Comment: [td-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td) cannot be the child of div-element.

Comment: @Esko Thank you! I cut the code out of the site that has it in the proper/normal usage. I should have been more attentive!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code can work, but you can not "test" with using only the tag `<td>` , you have to add the `<table><tr>` tags.

[see here it is working](http://jsfiddle.net/88g5jc4b/)

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class="param-value productrating-param" itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope="" itemtype="//schema.org/AggregateRating">

<div class="label-count">7</div>
<img src="http://www.lamianaturashop.com/custom/kencekonyha/catalog/view/theme/rome_cappuccino/image/stars_5.png" alt="5 / 5 csillag!" style="margin-top: 2px;">
<div id="new"></div>

</td>
 </tr></table>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are using td tag... it should be wrapped in table tag to make it work.. Or dont use td tag.. below is the solution using table.. but i will request you if your structre does not need any table then use div instead..

```js
var mylayer=$('.label-count').clone();

$('.productrating-param img').after(mylayer.text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="label-count">7</div>
<table>
    <td class="param-value productrating-param">
        <img src="http://www.lamianaturashop.com/custom/kencekonyha/catalog/view/theme/rome_cappuccino/image/stars_5.png" alt="5 / 5 csillag!" >
    </td>
  </table>
```

Comment: Thank you! This was because I cut it out of the site I'm testing the function to work.

Comment: NIce if this helped you, have a nice day